# c++ Fade between colors? (Arduino)

Tags: c++, arduino

I currently have this thats fading between 2 set colours:

```
for(int i=0;i<nLEDs;i++){
    a = (255 / 100) * (incomingByte * sensitivity);
    r = (r * 7 + a + 7) / 8;
    g = (g * 7 + (255 - a) + 7) / 8;
    b = 0;

    FTLEDColour col = { r , g , b };
    led.setLED(i, col);
  }
```

But now im trying to allow users to enter their own colours:

```
// > Colour fade, Start colour

int colFade1Red = 0;
int colFade1Green = 255;
int colFade1Blue = 0;

// > Colour fade, End colour

int colFade2Red = 255;
int colFade2Green = 0;
int colFade2Blue = 0;

int fadeAm = 7; // Fade speed
```

with the fading code:

```
void ColourFade(){
  for(int i=0;i<nLEDs;i++){

    r = ctest(colFade1Red, colFade2Red, r);
    g = ctest(colFade1Green, colFade2Green, g);
    b = ctest(colFade1Blue, colFade2Blue, b);

    FTLEDColour col = { r , g , b };
    led.setLED(i, col);
  }
}

int ctest(int col1, int col2, int cur){
   int temp = col1 - col2;
   if(temp < 0) { temp = -temp; } 

   int alp = (temp / 100) * (incomingByte * sensitivity);

   if(col1 < col2){
     return (cur * fadeAm + (col2 - alp) + fadeAm) / (fadeAm +1 );
   } else {
     return (cur * fadeAm + alp + fadeAm) / (fadeAm +1 );
   }
}
```

But this starts with the Second user colour and fades into pink. How would I fade colours properly?

Also "incomingByte" is a value between 0 and 100, and the code is in a update loop.

Comment: Regard `temp/100` will probably return 0 or 1 (it's an integer division). All your `ctest` is very confusing, it would be easier if you specify inputs, outputs and desired transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Smooth transitions between colours is best done in a different colour space (IMHO).

As an example, to transition from bright red to bright green, do you want to go via bright yellow (around the edge of the [colour wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_wheel)) or via #808000 (murky yellow) - which is what a straight line interpolation would give you in the RGB domain.

Having done this for my [Moodlamp app](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u7gW-0b6Pno), I used the [HSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) colour space.  I specified a start colour and end colour, along with a number of steps for the transition to take. That enabled me to calculate how much to adjust H, S and L by at each point in the transition.

Only at the point of *using* the colour did I convert back to RGB.

You can see the javascript code here (please bear in mind it's the first Javascript I ever wrote, so if it seems non-idiomatic, that's probably why!):

https://github.com/martinjthompson/MoodLamp/blob/master/app/assistants/lamp-assistant.js

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to fade to pink beacuse you are starting from red and ending with green.

To avoid this kind of mistake I suggest you to write an object oriented code.

If you don't want to write the classes to handle a 3D vectonr you can use the [Arduino Tinker Library](https://github.com/Nicola17/ArduinoTinkerLibrary)

I wrote this example for you:

```
#include <Vect3d.h>
#include <SerialLog.h>

Tinker::Vect3d<float> red(255,0,0);
Tinker::Vect3d<float> green(0,255,0);
Tinker::SerialLog serialLog;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  serialLog.display("Fade color example");  
  serialLog.endline();
}

void loop(){
  //fade factor computation
  const uint32_t t   = millis()%10000;
  const float cosArg = t/10000.*3.1415*2;
  const float fade   = abs(cos(cosArg));

  //Here's the color computation... as you can see is very easy to do!! :)
  Tinker::Vect3d<uint8_t> finalColor(red*fade + green*(1-fade));

  //We print the vect3d on the arduino serial port
  Tinker::LOG::displayVect3d(finalColor,&serialLog);
  serialLog.endline();
  delay(500);
}
```

Which prints the following output on the serial port

```
Fade color example
V[255;0;0]
V[242;12;0]
V[206;48;0]
V[149;105;0]
V[78;176;0]
V[0;254;0]
V[79;175;0]
V[150;104;0]
V[206;48;0]
V[242;12;0]
V[254;0;0]
V[242;12;0]
V[205;49;0]
V[148;106;0]
V[77;177;0]
V[1;253;0]
V[80;174;0]
V[151;103;0]
```

hope that this helps :)

Comment: How do you get the RGB values out of the final colour, I need to extract them to convert to a "FTLEDColour".

Comment: You can access a Vect3d with operator[]. So finalColor[0] is the red channel, finalColor[1] is the green and finalColor[2] is the blue channel.

Answer (score 0):

```
uint8_t clrR = abs(255 * cos(<some var that changes in time>));
```

same for clrB & clrG