# How to fade between two vectors by value?

Tags: c++, vector, arduino

I'm having issues working out how to fade between two colour vectors.

The two colours:

```
Tinker::Vect3d<float> startCol(255,0,0);
Tinker::Vect3d<float> endCol(0,0,255);
```

I also have an incoming value from 0-100 "t1".

And one of my trys:

```
for(int i=0;i<nLEDs;i++){

    const float fade   = (255 / 100) * (t1 * sensitivity);

    Tinker::Vect3d<float> finalColour(startCol*a + endCol*(1-a));  

    FTLEDColour col = { finalColour[0] , finalColour[1] , finalColour[2] };
}
```

The runs in a continuous loop. Im trying to start with Red and face to green based on the incoming value, so 0 is red and 100 is green.

Comment: Multiplying by `255 / 100` is wrong, if your input value is 0..100 and you want to scale to 0..1 you need to divide by 100.

Comment: I find colour fades work better using a different colour space than RGB. - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20469911/106092

Comment: If anyone wants to use the Tinker library you can find it on git hub https://github.com/Nicola17/ArduinoTinkerLibrary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I guess if you define a vector of float to define color, I guess its limits is between 0 .. 1, not 0 .. 255. i.e.:

```
Tinker::Vect3d<float> startCol(1.0,0,0);
Tinker::Vect3d<float> endCol(0,0,1.0);
```

and for your fade factor, you can do something like that:

```
const float fade   = (t1 * sensitivity)/100;
```

considering that t1 is varing between 0..100 and sensitivity is 0<= sensitivity <= 1

Now, you can apply your fade to your color as:

```
Tinker::Vect3d<float> finalColour(startCol*(1-fade) + endCol*(fade));
```

assuming, of course, that vector class can do this basic operations

P.S. you will only got a full fade if sensitivity is 1, which I guess it is not necessary for this equation.